# Java, nested class: how to access 'higher' level variable

Tags: java, list

i got an error when i run this code!

```
   private class ValuesClass {

            List<Float> value;

            public void addv(String _value) {
                    Float f = new Float(_value);
                    this.value.add(f);
            }
    }
```

This is the error returned

```
0.83
0.83
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.gsware.gsmarketanalyzer.StockQuote$ValuesClass.addv(StockQuote.java:216)
```

I don't know where is the error!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to instantiate the list, otherwise `value` is null:

```
List<Float> value = new ArrayList<Float>;
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
private class ValuesClass {

    List<Float> value;

    public void addv(String _value) {
        Float f = new Float(_value);
        if(this.value==null)
              this.value = new ArrayList<Float>();

        this.value.add(f);

    }
}
```

or

```
private class ValuesClass {

    List<Float> value = new ArrayList<Float>();

    public void addv(String _value) {
        Float f = new Float(_value);
        this.value.add(f);

    }
}
```

Comment: Additionaly, see this link for lazy initialization practices: http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=34

Answer (score 0):

**value** was not initialized and is therefore **null**

Answer (score 0):

The error was this

```
 List<Float> value;
```

solved with

```
List<Float> value = new ArrayList<Float>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you initialize `List<Float> value` anywhere before calling `addv`? With the code you've given it is null.

You can initialize it as follows:

```
List<Float> value = new ArrayList<Float>;
```

OR

Since `addv` isn't static you will need to instantiate ValuesClass and thus have the possibility of lazy initializing `value`:

```
public ValuesClass(){
    this.value = new ArrayList<Float>;
}
```

Comment: Updated the answer with lazy initialization approach.